# How to instal no flo on a mac to show the visual interface

Tags: noflo

Im trying to install and play with no flo. I have a Mac 10.9.5.
I have tried to follow the instructions as detailed in http://noflojs.org/documentation/. I've installed noflo, built the project and got the calculator to run. Lovely. However there's also the instructions here: http://noflojs.org/documentation/installation/ which I assume I don't have to do because its about installing from git and I've already got noflo installed. It has something confusing about grunt which I've never used before and which is confusing as you have to install grunt globally as well as locally for each subfolder. However I think I dont need to do this (correct me if I'm wrong) as I've already got no flo to work on the command line.

My question is: how do I get the visual interface with all the draggable components to work on my mac now that I've got noflo installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The visual IDE used for NoFlo is Flowhub. It is separate from NoFlo itself, because it can also be used with other FBP/data-flow runtimes.

Setup Flowhub for
 [NoFlo on node.js](http://docs.flowhub.io/getting-started-node/) or [NoFlo on browser](http://docs.flowhub.io/getting-started-browser/)